# Use LINQ to pull data where rows match other rows

Tags: performance, linq

I'm pretty new to LINQ, but I'm trying to find a fast way to take a set of data and pull out only rows where particular columns have duplicates in other rows. E.g. in a set of people, pull out only people who share a phone number with another person. Here's a breakdown of what I'm up to:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public int Province { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string Web { get; set; }
}
```

And then I want to sort them in different ways to look for possible duplicates in my input values, so if I want to find where Address Line 1 and Postal Code match, I can sort it like so:

`IOrderedEnumerable<Person> sortedPeople = people.OrderBy(x => x.AddressLine1).ThenByDescending(x => x.PostalCode);`

And then just go through and bundle any matches together, but there will be a *lot* of data that doesn't match anything, so if I can cull it out in the first place, it could potentially save a lot of time.

I have a suspicion it will end up costing me more time than it would save, but I figured I'd ask if there's an efficient way.

Comment: You have list  of Persons, or you want to find duplicates in database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sorting lines won't find duplicates. If you want to find duplicates, you need to make groups of Persons that share something, for instance Persons that have the same PostalCode, or that live in the same City.

Making groups of items that share something is done by using [one of the overloads of Enumerable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-5.0). The most important parameter of `GroupBy` is parameter `keySelector`. With this parameter you say what should be the common value for all Persons in the group.

The following will give you a sequence of Groups of Persons. All Persons in the group have the same City. The group is identified by the `Key`, which has the value of the common element. So you have a Group with all Parisians, with key "Paris"; Another group contains all Amsterdammers with key "Amsterdam", etc

```
var result = persons.GroupBy(person => person.City);
```

However, you don't want to keep all groups, you only want to keep groups that have more than one member: those are the groups that have duplicates.

```
var duplicateCitizens = persons.GroupBy(person => person.City)
    .Where(group => group.Skip(1).Any());
```

In words: first make groups of persons that live in the same City. Then from every group, keep only those groups that have more than one element (= if you skip one element, there are still elements left).

I use the `Skip(1).Any()` method for efficiency reasons. If you already know after the 1st element that there are duplicates, why continue counting all hundred elements?

The result is a sequence of Groups of more than one Person. All Persons in the group live in the same city. The Key of the group is the City that they have in common.

Answer (score 0):

You can group the results by the phone number:

```
var query = Persons.GroupBy(p => p.Phone)
          .Where(p => p.Count() > 1)
          .ToList();
```

After this you have a grouped list with the phone number as key and the persons with the matching number if this number is more than one time assigned.